# Xcode: declare method in public header only in DEBUG mode

Tags: objective-c, methods, integration-testing, public

I am developing a framework that connects to a hard coded url. I'd like to be able to change that url in automated tests. I adding the following to my umbrella header:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
- (void)setServerUrl;
#endif
```

I thought that if I build the framework in `-configuration Release` mode, the preprocessor would delete the method declaration from the code, which is what I want.

So, maybe my approach was wrong to begin with, or it was right but the implementation wasn't. In any case, how do I expose a method in DEBUG mode only? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put this method in public header.
In yours automated test add category, that makes this method visible for them.